# How to check whether a given $W(x,p)$ represents a Wigner function of a physical state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, wigner-transform

For simplicity let us consider one-dimensional quantum-mechanical systems only. Given any state $\rho\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ and its Wigner function $W_\rho(x,p)$, there are several properties it always satisfies,

- it is real-valued and bounded in absolute value by $2/\hbar$ from above,
- its marginals are well-behaved probability distributions,
- its overlap $\int W_\rho(x,p) W_\sigma(x,p) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}p$ with the Wigner function of any other state $\sigma$ is nonnegative.

Given an arbitrary function $W(x,p)$, we can reconstruct a state $\rho$ it corresponds to iff all of these conditions are met using the Weyl transform. If some properties are not satisfied, the resulting operator will be unphysical—non-Hermitian, unnormalized or non-positive. The question is how to check the conditions prior to the calculation.

The first two are usually fairly easy to check but the latter involves going through all states of the system. Even if we restrict ourselves to pure states, this still iterates over all rays in an infinite-dimensional linear vector space and is as such usually done finding a proof tailored to the specific case. Is there a simpler (algorithmic) condition which can replace the third bullet above and implies its validity?

Comment: [answered in](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177406/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-a-function-to-be-the-wigner-function-of/206308#206308)

Comment: @CosmasZachos: If think that questions are duplicates of one another (as they seem to be in this case), please use the `flag` link below the question and flag one of them as duplicate of the other.