Is there a non-negative normalized Wigner function that doesn't correspond to a physical state?
This is related to Is the Wigner function non-negative only for convex mixtures of Gaussian states? and Can the characteristic function $\chi_\rho(\beta)={\rm tr}[\rho D(\beta)]$ be an indicator function?, but focusing on a more specific aspect.
Let's consider the simplest single-mode case for simplicity. We know how to derive the Wigner function corresponding to any given density matrix.
Can we reverse this process and be ensured to always get a density matrix? In particular, given a non-negative normalised Wigner function $W_\rho(\alpha)$, are we ensured that the corresponding operator $\rho$ is a density matrix? If not, what's a counterexample?

What makes you think a non-negative WF has absolutely anything to do with a density matrix or not? There is an implicit misunderstanding there... Positivity of operators is completely unrelated to positive-semidefiniteness of WFs, of course.

Bracken, A.J. and Wood, J.G., 2004. Non-positivity of Groenewold operators. Europhysics Letters, 68(1), p.1.

https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/36/23/101

@CosmasZachos sure, you're right, positive is a red herring here. I'm asking for examples of (normalized) Wigners which do not correspond to a density matrix. Though I'm particularly interested in examples where the Wigner is non-negative, that's not the main ingredient I guess. Can you clarify what you're meaning to point out in those papers?

@CosmasZachos the focus on non-negativity comes  by analogy with what happens with  the $P$. Unless I'm misunderstanding something here (which is possible), if $P(\alpha)$ is any non-negative normalized (possibly sufficiently regular) function, then there's a corresponding state (that's a mixture of coherents). Though just asking for $P$ to be normalized (but not non-negative) you might not get density matrices, trivial counterexample being $P(\alpha)=-\delta^2(\alpha)$. So I've been looking for a simple counterexample showing that for the Wigner the situation is different

the second paper above probably answers the question, I'm going through it. Section 4 might be converted in a simple counterexample, though I'm not entirely sure yet

related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177406/58382
